# How to display the output of dynamic query in form of a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a huge dynamic query in Oracle PL/SQL. My requirement is to display this query output in form of a table. I have saved the dynamic query in a variable. Now loop it by using cursors. But the output is not in form of table. Below is a short example:

```
set serveroutput on

declare 
TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
v_emp_cursor EmpCurTyp;
var1 varchar2(1000) :='select document_id  from blu_payment_report_history' ;
var2 varchar(100) := ' where rownum <=3 ';
output varchar(100);
finalvar varchar(100);

begin
finalvar:= var1 || ' ' || var2;
OPEN v_emp_cursor FOR finalvar;
  LOOP
    FETCH v_emp_cursor INTO output;
    dbms_output.put_line(output);
    EXIT WHEN v_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
 CLOSE v_emp_cursor;
end;
```

How to modify the above code to bring output in form of table.
Note: This is only an example with one column. My actual query has 10 columns.

Below is the output of my query. But this is not in form of table:
[image]

Error screenshot and compiled stored procedure screenshot  :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't tag lots of irrelevant client applications. If you are using PowerBI then tag that and don't tag other clients such as SQL Developer or PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: The code has to be executed in PL/SQL Developer. If it executes successfully here power BI will not be a problem. So I am removing the Power BI tag as per your suggestion.

Comment: Let me try to explain again my problem. I need to get PL/SQL output in form of table with proper structure and not in any print format.

Comment: You appear to be confusing **displaying** data and returning data. You probably just want to return the data to PowerBI (whereas for PL/SQL developer you want to both return **and** display the data).

Comment: In the final image, do not select "Text", select "Stored Procedure" and refer to the PowerBI documentation as to how to pass variables and handle returned cursors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_payment_report_history(
  v_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
  v_sql varchar2(1000) := 'select document_id from blu_payment_report_history where rownum <=3 ';
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur FOR v_sql;
END;
/
```

This will return a result set which contains rows and columns.

How you choose to **display** it is irrelevant; the cursor will contain rows and columns.

In PL/SQL developer, you need to both return the result set and **display** the cursor to the console using your code:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_col1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  get_payment_report_history(v_cur);

  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur INTO v_col1;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(output);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_cur;
END; 
/
```

In PowerBI, you would call the stored procedure and then process the returned cursor; you do not need a PL/SQL wrapper around the returned results to display it.

---

Instead of returning a cursor, in Oracle 12 and later, you could also use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` to implicitly return a cursor.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_payment_report_history
IS
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql varchar2(1000) := 'select document_id from blu_payment_report_history where rownum <=3 ';
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur FOR v_sql;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_cur);
END;
/
```

Then if your client supports it use:

```sql
EXECUTE get_payment_report_history();
```

To call the procedure, which will implicitly return the result set contained in the cursor.

Comment: Your both solutions are giving errors. In the first solution when I try to return the result set and display the cursor to the console, I get error "table or view does not exist" and in the second solution also I get the same error.

Comment: I have attached the error screenshot in my question above from the second solution. exec get_payment_report_history() is giving error

Comment: @sam The `select document_id from blu_payment_report_history` section is taken from **YOUR** code in the question. If the table does not exist then we cannot help that because it is the code **YOU** gave us in the question. **YOU** need to debug that part of the problem and find the correct table name because we do not have access to **YOUR** database.

Comment: Table name is correct. When I do select document_id from blu_payment_report_history I get the output. I guess it is the procedure execution right access causing this issue. it’s strange I can create proc but not execute it? But anyways , I’ll accept your solution and thank you for your efforts and time.

Comment: Will sure let you know once it works.